Downgrade Python 3 to python 2
I am running the new version (May'24) of Pi OS on my Pi Zero and Pi Nano.
The programmes I wish to run were written for python2 and am led to believe that this can be incompatible with Python3, so wish to acquire python2 to run them.
How do i downgrade my software, or if thats not possible how do get (or identify) an older version of the Imager which will contain python2.
Thanks.

Why not just convert your Python2 code to Python3? Not normally difficult!

I thought getting the Python 2 OS would be easier as there are several programme modules and I have a spare SD card, but thanks, I'll look it up.

If The programs were written for python2 they are probably very old and a newer version has been released. Consider looking for that instead.

You can have Python 2 and 3 installed at the same time. Of course, only one will be the default, when you run the python command. When you have multiple installed, there will be a python2 command and a python3 command as well.
To run a script with a specific version you can either invoke it like python2 my-script.py, or put it in the shebang line of an executable script (like: #!/usr/bin/env python2 as the first line).
But as others mentioned, you should first look into upgrading your code to use Python3. That would be a more future-proof solution.
I'm not sure the precise command to install Python2, but it should be something like: sudo apt install python2.
Note: this will also provide separate pip2 and pip3 commands, so you can install modules for one version or the other without conflicts.
